# Query with 3 tables for receive data

Tags: mysql

The idea is user can chose one line and one road and get the schedule. Can someone help me with a mysql query?

I have 3 tables on my database

**Example :**

Table Roads

```
Id | RoadName 
1  | StackoverflowRoad
```

Table Lines

```
Id | Linename 
1  | StackoverflowLine
```

Table hours

```
HoursLineId | HoursRoadId | hours
1           |  2          | 8:35:13
```

Comment: It's only a question because i dont remember  how to inner join tables so  yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use inner join in order to join the 3 tables based on foreign keys.

```
SELECT * FROM hours 
    INNER JOIN Roads ON Roads.Id=hours.HoursRoadId 
    INNER JOIN Lines ON hours.HoursLineId=Lines.Id 
    where Roads.Id='Your ID' AND Lines.Id='Your Id';
```

This will get the schedule after filtering by **Line Id** and **Road Id**.